# The value fetched in the textinput need to passed as an argument to insert in database

Tags: database, sqlite, react-native, textinput

One textinput has a value from geocoder and this value has to be passed to another state value,so that it can be inserted to database

This render has the value location which is fetched from city variable from geocoder.

```
<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.inputs}
                  placeholder="Project Location:"
                  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                 onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ location: value })}
                 value = {this.state.city.toString()}
                />
              </View>
```

This value location has to be inserted to the database.But the location is not passed here and it shows undefined.

```
sync() {
    console.log('inside sync function');
    console.log(this.state.location);

    const { projid } = this.state;
     const { client } = this.state;
      const { contractor } = this.state;
       const { title } = this.state;
        const { location } = this.state;
         const { desc } = this.state;
          const { unit } = this.state;
           const { drill } = this.state;
            const { logger } = this.state;

     //alert(user_name, user_contact, user_address);

     if (projid) {
       if (client) {
         if (contractor) {
           if (title) {
             if (location) {
               if (desc) {
                 if (unit) {
                   if (drill) {
                     if (logger) {
           db.transaction(function(tx) {
             tx.executeSql(
               'INSERT INTO projInfo (projectId,client,contractor,title,location,description,unit,drillers,loggers) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
               [projid, client, contractor, title,location,desc,unit,drill,logger],
               (tx, results) => {
                 console.log('Results', results.rowsAffected);
                 if (results.rowsAffected > 0) {
                   Alert.alert(
                     'Success',
                     'Inserted Successfully',
                     [
                       {
                         text: 'Ok'
                       },
                     ],
                     { cancelable: false }
                   );
                 } else {
                   alert('Insert Failed');
                 }
               }
             );
           });
          } else {
             alert('Please fill loggers');
          }
            } else {
             alert('Please fill drillers');
           }
             }else {
              alert('Please fill unit');
            }
              } else {
              alert('Please fill description');
            }
              } else {
              alert('Please fill location');
            }
               } else {
              alert('Please fill title');
            }
               } else {
              alert('Please fill contractor');
            }
                } else {
              alert('Please fill client');
            }
                } else {
               alert('Please fill project ID');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it the same screen?

Comment: yes same screen